# Asp.net MVC SQL Server State IIS 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, session-state

Is it possible to implement SQL Session State with ASP.NET MVC without the addition of code to our webapp?  We need this to be a transparent switch from In-proc to SQLServer.

Comment: I realized the wepapp I was testing this with was in fact not utilizing any sessions..how embarrassing.  Now my session is being saved to the temp table (as it should)!  However, when I recycle the app pool my session LockDateLocal is updated to the current time and I'm required to log back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No code is required in your application to switch from in process to SQL session state. This is controlled from with your applications web.config file. The one thing you will have to do is run the necessary scripts to create the ASP.NET Session database and tables. See this [Microsoft support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604) for more details. This is the same for web forms as well as MVC.

Comment: I ran the scripts in SQL Management Studio but I don't have the Query Analyzer.  After I ran InstallPersistSqlState.SQL I configured IIS and was unable to get any sessions in the temp table unless I programmatically assigned a value to some session variable.

Comment: I was missing my machine key entries! :)